# Is there a Printer Driver for a Fuji Xerox Docu Print CM205B Laser Printer?

Tags: drivers, printing

I am very new to Ubuntu, having sold Windows based (and MSDOS + CP/M) computers for the last 30 years. How do I get a Fuji Xerox Docu Print CM205B Laser Printer working under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Please ask only one question per thread. When it comes to print drivers, I found this: The [official site](http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.au/en/support/Downloads.aspx?product=9933&category=5726) has both Windows and Mac drivers. Ubuntu uses the same printing system as Mac OSX, so you should be fine.

I guess you should be able to just plug in the printer, possibly do an "Add printer", and select it from the list. If you have trouble, you can try to figure out how to install the Mac drivers, or since it's a laser printer, you can likely use one of the generic PostScript drivers.

I'm looking for more specific info, but the Linux Printing website seems to be having trouble at the moment. I'll update this answer with more info as I find it.